# jquery XML parse last 3 documents

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using Jquery to parse an xml document and add content to my home page.

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://blog.voipinnovations.com/blog/rss.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
                        var Col0 = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var Col1 = $(this).find('category').text();
                        var Col2 = $(this).find('author').text();

                        $("#RSScontainer").append("<p>" + Col0 + "</p>" + "<p>" + Col1 + "</p>" + "<p>" + Col2 + "</p> <hr />");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

It works perfectly. I just have one small question. How do I only parse the last 3 items? I tried writing a for loop but that didn't work. Sorry if this seems obvious.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, what do you mean by last 3 documents?

Comment: Sorry If im unclear. This returns around 30 articles. I only want to display the last three. So i want the .find("item").each(function(){} code to only run 3 times.

Comment: @onTheInternet did my answer worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this.Use [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) of jquery.

```
success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('item').slice(-3).each(function () {
                        var Col0 = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var Col1 = $(this).find('category').text();
                        var Col2 = $(this).find('author').text();    
                        $("#RSScontainer").append("<p>" + Col0 + "</p>" + "<p>" + Col1 + "</p>" + "<p>" + Col2 + "</p> <hr />");
                        });
                        }
```

Comment: what if you use `$(xml).find('item').slice(-3)`